# Analysis Services CommitTransaction causes AS hanged

Tags: ssas, cube

After I process a cube and commit transaction, something will be wrong with AS. No response when connect to AS using Management Studio.
The cube has two partitions which contains 100,000,000 fact records in each.

Processing is completed and I have confirmed that by using SQL Server profiler. But the CommitTransaction event never finish. What is worse is that Analysis Services will not response.

Hope someone can help me.

Thanks,

Comment: did u get a solution to your problem?